# Sorting a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

Im trying to sort a matrix by the sum of its row's digits, from highest to lowest. I dont know if i explained that correctly so here's some photos explaining it.

[image]

This is what my code outputs. Basically, it asks you for m and n, which are the dimensions of the matrix. In this example it's a 3x4, 3 rows and 4 columns. Then, the matrix should be sorted by rows, by the sum of row's digits. Which means, instead of what's being outputted in the picture above, the correct result should be this:

[image]

I have no idea how to sort this from highest to lowest, i have been trying for hours to no avail.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 30
    
void main(){
double a[N][N], s[N], p;
int i, j, m, n, max;

while(1){
    
    printf("\nm, n? ");
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

    if(m <= 0 || m > N || n <=0 || n > N)
        break;

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        printf("%2d. row? ", i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < n; scanf("%lf", &a[i][j++]));
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(s[i] = j = 0; j < n; s[i] += a[i][j++]);

    for(j = 0; j < n - 1; j++){
        for(max = i, j = i+1; j < n; j++)
            if(s[j] > s[max])
                max = i;
                if(max != j){
                    p = s[j];
                    s[j] = s[max];
                    s[max] = p;
                    for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
                        p = a[j][i];
                        a[j][i] = a[j][max];
                        a[j][max] = p;
                    }
                }
    }
    printf("New matrix: \n");

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; printf("%8.2lf", a[i][j++]));
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
        printf("-------------");
    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < m; printf("%8.2f \n", s[j++]));
    printf("\n"); 
}
}
```

Comment: [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). Forget the sum complexity. Do you know how to sort numbers high to low? Remove the `scanf` for now, it's only wasting time. Hardcode some values to start. I also recommend adding some functions. You've got a very busy `main` function.

Comment: Unless I had some very specific requirements, I would use [the standard `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) instead of coming up with my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the rows of the matrix from highest to lowest, using a simple bubble sort algorithm.Your code modified below:

```
int main() {

  double a[N][N], s[N], p;
  int i, j, m, n, max;

  while (1) {
    printf("\nm, n? ");
    scanf("%d%d", & m, & n);

    if (m <= 0 || m > N || n <= 0 || n > N)
      break;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      printf("%2d. row? ", i + 1);
      for (j = 0; j < n; scanf("%lf", & a[i][j++]));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (s[i] = j = 0; j < n; s[i] += a[i][j++]);

    for (i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) { // modified here
      for (j = i + 1; j < m; j++) { // modified here
        if (s[j] > s[i]) { // modified here
          p = s[i];
          s[i] = s[j];
          s[j] = p;
          for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            p = a[i][k];
            a[i][k] = a[j][k];
            a[j][k] = p;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    printf("New matrix: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < n; printf("%8.2lf", a[i][j++]));
      printf("\n");
    }
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
      printf("-------------");
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < m; printf("%8.2f \n", s[j++]));
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

*Here's how i modified your code to achieve that:*

- Initialize a loop variable i to 0.

---

- In the outer loop, run the inner loop j from i+1 to m-1.

---

- In the inner loop, compare the sum of the row i with the sum of row
  j. If the sum of row j is greater than the sum of row i, swap the
  rows using a temporary variable.

---

- After the inner loop finishes, increment the value of i by 1. Repeat
  the outer loop until i becomes equal to m-1.

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `qsort` to let it handle the sorting and item swapping. Then you only need to write the code for comparing two rows with each other.

Given something like this:

```
int matrix[3][4] = 
{
  {1,2,3,4},
  {5,6,7,8},
  {9,1,2,3},
};
```

You'd call `qsort` as:

```
qsort(matrix, 3, sizeof(int[4]), compare);
```

The only complexity is implementing the comparison callback function. There's two things to consider there:

- We've told `qsort` that we have an array of 3 items, each of type `int[4]`. So the void pointers it passes along to us will actually be pointers to type `int[4]`. That is: `int(*)[4]`.
- `qsort` sorts in ascending order by default, where the item considered "less" ends up first. So we need to tweak that to get the largest item first.

Example:

```
int compare (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  const int (*ptr1)[4] = obj1;
  const int (*ptr2)[4] = obj2;
  size_t sum1=0;
  size_t sum2=0;

  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    sum1 += (*ptr1)[i];
    sum2 += (*ptr2)[i];
  }

  if(sum1 > sum2) // largest sum considered "less" for qsort
    return -1;
  else
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

`sum1 < sum2` would have placed the smallest row first.

---

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  const int (*ptr1)[4] = obj1;
  const int (*ptr2)[4] = obj2;
  size_t sum1=0;
  size_t sum2=0;
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    sum1 += (*ptr1)[i];
    sum2 += (*ptr2)[i];
  }

  if(sum1 > sum2) // largest sum considered "less" for qsort
    return -1;
  else
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

void print_matrix(size_t col, size_t row, int matrix[col][row])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<col; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<row; j++)
    {
      printf("%d,", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  int matrix[3][4] = 
  {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,1,2,3},
  };

  print_matrix(3,4,matrix);
  puts("");
  qsort(matrix, 3, sizeof(int[4]), compare);
  print_matrix(3,4,matrix);
}
```